# How does broker knows there is a MQRFH2 header

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

We have a compute node that copies OutputRoot from InputRoot having MQRFH2 header  and then sets MQMD format as 'MQSTR   ' before sending it to an MQOutput node.

On my local system(MQ and WMB 7.0) when I try to test the flow and browse output queue from RFHUTILC the message still have MQMD format as MQHRF2 with proper MQRFH2 header details.

While this same flow when tested in other test regions is giving an output message with blank MQMD format and RFH2 details comes in message payload.

What can be the reason of this difference?

Answer (score 0):

The input message will have the RFH2 header at InputRoot.MQRFH2, or at InputRoot.MQRFH2C if you use the compact parser for RFH2, which will be copied to the OutputRoot, and Broker sets the MQMD Format to MQHRF2 when it sees that header in the OutputRoot.

To delete the RFH2 header you should do something like this:

```
SET OutputRoot.MQMD.Format = OutputRoot.MQRFH2.Format;
SET OutputRoot.MQRFH2 = NULL;
```

I can't think of an explanation for the different behavior you see, and I don't have a V7 Broker to test. By the way you shouldn't have one either as it is out of support.

Comment: The actual scenario where RFH2 header is not coming is on expiration report message(message was stored with report option to send back full data on expiry) but the message payload begin as RFH ... <usr>[correct usr data from original message]</usr>. I tried to simulate the same on my local system but on my local system there is no message payload/data but the message has the correct RFH2 header as original message. Any idea what can be the issue.